# Install Sphinx 2.2.9 on OS X

Tags: macos, sphinx

I have downloaded the Mac OS X 10.10.x x86_64 binaries and extracted the files:

1. I end up what a folder named sphinx-2.2.9-release-osx10.10-x86_64.
2. There is no configure program in the sphinx-2.2.9-release-osx10.10-x86_64 folder.
3. In the documentation there are no sections on installation on OS X.

Following the compiling for Linux seemed possible, but for the missing configure program.  There are sections for various Linux flavors and Windows.

There has to be something obvious I'm missing here, but I've searched for quite a while and can find nothing.